# Grid Like Snake system

Tags: unity-game-engine

all. What I am trying to accomplish is a simple game of snake where each tail position follows the previous tail position. But for some reason, the tiles follow the previous tail position diagonally instead of just moving in a grid system like the head does. Here is my code

Head Movement Class

```
public float unitsPerFrame = 1;
void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && downDir == false)
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
            mDir = Vector3.up * unitsPerFrame;
        }
    }
```

... All of the directions are the same, I just included this so you can see how my head movement functions.

Tail Movement Class

```
 void Update()
{
    tail[0].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(tail[0].transform.localPosition, GameObject.Find("Player").transform.localPosition, 0.02f);
    for(int i = 1; i < tail.Count; i++)
    {
        tail[i].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(tail[i].transform.localPosition, tail[i - 1].transform.localPosition, 0.02f);
        tail[i].transform.rotation = tail[i - 1].transform.rotation;
    }
}
```

Also just for clarification, I know I am using a Vector3, when I should be using vector2 for a 2D, but it is functioning correctly right now and I will change this later.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `Vector3.MoveTowards` = *Moves a point `current` in a straight line towards a `target` point.* Referenced from [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html). 
In fact a **straight line** would be the shortest path and in your case a diagonal, however to achieve your goal, you have several options: I will describe two of them

> 1. Replace the position of `tail x` with `tail x - 1` Example:
>    `tail[i].transform.position = tail[i - 1].transform.position;`
> 2. Using Linear Interpolation (do this if you want a smooth movement between tiles) Example:
>    `tail[i].transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(tail[i].transform.position, tail[i - 1].transform.position, Time.deltaTime);`